# How to run LINQ function in Java script to return an object from an Array

Tags: javascript, linq

I have a javascript Array of object like this:

```js
var PriorityList =[]
PriorityList.push({ Id: 4, Title: 'Very High' });
PriorityList.push({ Id: 3, Title: 'High' });
PriorityList.push({ Id: 2, Title: 'Normal' });
PriorityList.push({ Id: 1, Title: 'low' });
PriorityList.push({ Id: 1, Title: 'Very low' });
```

I want to choose find one of them by Id and return it's Title
In c# I can run this code:

```cs
var selPer = PriorityList.Find(2).Title;
```

Or

```cs
var selPer = PriorityList.First(p=>p.Id==2).Title;
```

but In JS , I don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript also has a [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which is very similar to the LINQ `.First()` method. It returns the first element that matches the given filter criteria. The only real difference to `.First()` is that [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) does not throw an Exception when no matching element was found but instead returns `undefined`.

```
var PriorityList = [];
PriorityList.push({Id: 4, Title: "Very High"});
PriorityList.push({Id: 3, Title: "High"});
PriorityList.push({Id: 2, Title: "Normal"});
PriorityList.push({Id: 1, Title: "low"});
PriorityList.push({Id: 1, Title: "Very low"});

PriorityList.find(item => item.Id === 2).Title; // "Normal"
```